# Export data from Share point to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In my Share point there is an excel and I would like to export that data to local excel copy in my machine. Would it be possible through Excel VBA ?, Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Sadly your question as of now is too-broad for the Q&A style format of this website. I recommend you read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of the help page and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57659342/edit) your question accordingly

Comment: Thank you @MindSwipe , can you help me with the answer?

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether the data is an Excel file hosted on SharePoint or something else. Clarify what you want to do in your question, so people can help.

Comment: @jessi , Thank you ! and Yes ! data is in the form of list available in SharePoint , that list has to be exported or downloaded as Excel file into the local .Due to some policies I cannot exactly show the how data looks like as its confidential bank data .

Comment: I have not tried this  myself, but this answer from Sharepoint Stack Exchange may be helpful [Import Sharepoint List into Excel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29021/import-sharepoint-list-into-excel-using-vba-only)